# "UNION ALL" not retrieving results, or incorrectly and duplicating results when it does

Tags: php, join, union

First let me explain I'm not very familiar with retrieving data from two or more tables. I have two tables, one for images and the other for videos. I am attempting to pull entries from both to list together on one page and ordered together so they're mixed in with each other in the results.

The code is as follows...

```
            $result_media = @mysql_query(" 
                (SELECT 
                videos.url AS video_url,  
                videos.description AS video_description
                FROM videos)

                UNION ALL

                (SELECT 
                images.url AS image_url
                FROM images
                WHERE (images.url != 'nopic.png') ) LIMIT 25");

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_media)) {

                $video_url = $row['videos_url'];
                $video_thumbnail = $row['video_thumbnail'];
                $video_description = $row['video_description'];

                $image_url = $row['image_url'];

                [echo results]
            }
```

Nothing is displayed unless I remove ", videos.description AS video_description" but then of course the data doesn't show up right.

Secondly, when I do get results to display (worked with INNER JOIN) all results are duplicated.

Any ideas?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is there any relationship between videos and images? If none, then JOIN syntax won't help. If you do UNION syntax, you need the same number of columns in all select statements, so it can append the next select result after the first. They all need to be named (as) the same column too. If theres no actual reason to keep images with videos... your best bet, is just to make two seperate sql queries and handle each results as you need.

Comment: However if there IS a relationship between images and videos... you are going to need a single field in both tables to 'join' on that relate them. Generally a foreign key of some sort in one or both tables.

Comment: A few of the columns are named the same and serve the same function, for example "url" in both tables, (which is why I was trying to differentiate between the two with "images.url AS image_url", etc) as the actual URL's point to different locations on the server.

Comment: Could I use "id" column (as an example) to "join" them?

Comment: Right, but you cannot join on url, because thats not what makes a video relate to an image. You'd need something like `video_id` in the `images` table, then join on that... or vice versa, an `image_id` in the `videos` table, like `JOIN videos.id = images.video_id`. Is it always going to be a one-to-one relation?

Comment: Gotcha... trying to use a `unique_id` column (in both tables, correct?). Not sure what you mean by a one-to-one relation but if both these columns will serve the same purpose (such as a unique id that has a random id generated), then yes. With all this do both tables still need the same number of columns?

Comment: For example... `SELECT * FROM videos INNER JOIN images ON videos.uniqueid = images.uniqueid` ?

Comment: By one-to-one I meant, is there only ever one image row, relating to one video row. Or are there multiple images for each video... or multiple videos for each image. You could join on `uniqueid` ... if they relate. Like, if images.uniqueid = 400... and videos.uniqueid = 400 ... those two rows actually belong together, since you will be joining them on that 400 value and returning the urls and details from that row in both tables.